# C# Login detail storage

Tags: c#, authentication, storage

I have this login form on my program in C#, I will be matching the username and password in my website database then when i get a repsonse that says true, it will then store the user details inside the program, I don't want to use an external file to store the details, is it possible to be able to embed the user details inside the program.

once the user uses the program again, it will check whether the user details are still embedded inside the program, which will then keep the user "logged" in.

I have a gut feeling that embedded resources cannot be edited in realtime though.

What's the best method to store username/password for future uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, yes you can store the "cookie" which is the term I'd use for the "user details" you're describing inside your application (BTW I think another term for the "cookie" is an "authentication ticket".)

However, typically a user won't have permission to modify the exe which they are running. And, there's great support in the framework for storing information outside the application...

I think you're best storing this in some sort of private area which only the user of your C# program can see. Check out Isolated Storage for this. And perhaps encrypt it too.

Say you have a string which represents the data you want to save called state (you could serialize a serializable class to a string.) You can save it like so:

```
private static IsolatedStorageFile _isoStore =
                    IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null);
String state = "my Secret String";
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream oStream =
                    new IsolatedStorageFileStream(C_CREDENTIALS_FILENAME, 
                                                    FileMode.Create, 
                                                    _isoStore))
            {
                Byte[] stateBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(state);
                Byte[] encryptedBytes = ProtectedData.Protect(stateBytes, 
                                                                null, 
                                                                DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
                oStream.Write(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);
```

C_CREDENTIAL_FILENAME is the name of the file you want to store the information in. To get it back try something like this:

```
string[] fileNames = _isoStore.GetFileNames(C_CREDENTIALS_FILENAME);
            if (fileNames.Any(item => item == C_CREDENTIALS_FILENAME))
            {
                //it exists
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream iStream =
                    new IsolatedStorageFileStream(C_CREDENTIALS_FILENAME, FileMode.Open, _isoStore))
                {
                    Byte[] unEncryptedBytes = ProtectedData.Unprotect(iStream.ToArray(),
                                                null,
                                                DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
                    String unEncryptedXml = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(unEncryptedBytes);
                                    }
            }
            else
            { 
                //it doesn't exist
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, you have solved my issue! :D Isolated Storage worked really well, thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, a running executable file can't be modified in Windows, therefore you can't edit "embedded" data.

There's a couple of alternatives, to name a couple from the top of my head:

- Protected storage
- System registry
- App.settings file

Comment: Thank you for some ideas :D will keep those in mind for future project, once again, thank you.